# How to play loop an audio clip on button hold down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I'am trying to make a 3rd person shooter prototype. I got the gun down, so it shoots, but there is a problem with the audio. When I click the shooting button, it plays the audio, and that is good, but when I hold down the shooting button the sound doesn't play, only when I release it. Can you help? I'am just a starter programmer, watching tutorials and learning while trying to understand the code, but I'am still bad at it. I'am on C# by the way. Here is the code (I just coppied the whole gun script):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0f, 2f)]
    private float fireRate = 1;

    [SerializeField]
    [Range(1, 10)]
    private int damage = 1;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform firePoint;

    [SerializeField]

        private ParticleSystem muzzleParticle;
    
        [SerializeField]
        private AudioSource gunFireSource;
    
        private float timer;
    
        void Update()
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer >= fireRate)
            {
                if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
                {
                    timer = 0f;
                    FireGun();
                }
            }
        }
    
        private void FireGun()
        {
            //Debug.DrawRay(firePoint.position, firePoint.forward * 100, Color.red, 2f);
    
            muzzleParticle.Play();
            gunFireSource.Play();
    
            Ray ray = new Ray(firePoint.position, firePoint.forward);
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
    
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, 100))
            {
                var health = hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Health>();
    
                if (health != null)
                    health.TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        }
    }
```

P.s. The tutorials I follow is by Jason Weimann.

Comment: You can try `gunFireSource.Stop()` before `gunFireSource.Play()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that

```
gunFireSource.Play();
```

**re**starts the sound everytime. See [`AudioSource.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html)

> If `AudioSource.clip` is set to the same clip that is playing then the clip will sound like it is re-started. `AudioSource` will assume any `Play` call will have a new audio clip to play.

So if your fire rate is to low you never give the sound a chance to play.

---

You could use [`AudioSource.PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html)

> `AudioSource.PlayOneShot` does not cancel clips that are already being played by `AudioSource.PlayOneShot` and `AudioSource.Play`.

like

```
gunFireSource.PlayOneShot(gunFireSource.clip);
```

which allows to play multiple overlapping sounds.

---

Or alternatively you could only start a new sound after another has finished by checking for [`AudioSource.isPlaying`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-isPlaying.html)

> Is the clip playing right now?

like

```
if(!gunFireSource.isPlaying) gunFireSource.Play();
```

---

Or as another alternative for looping the sound but immediately stopping when you release the button you would enable `AudioSource.loop` either via the Inspector or in `Awake`. And then do

```
void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer >= fireRate)
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            timer = 0f;
            FireGun();
        }
    }
    if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire"))
    {
        if(gunFireSource.isPlaying) gunFireSource.Stop();
    }
}
```

And as before only start the sound once

```
if(!gunFireSource.isPlaying) gunFireSource.Play();
```

---

Btw you can simply the raycast and component check a bit. IMO it is better readable like

```
var ray = new Ray(firePoint.position, firePoint.forward);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hitInfo, 100))
{
    if(hitInfo.collider.TryGetComponent<Health>(out var health))
    {
        health.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```